# How can I send Mongodb Atlas alert notifications to a specific Slack channel using WebHooks?

Tags: terraform, webhooks, mongodb-atlas

We are in the middle of migrating to Mongodb Atlas and I am trying to set up some monitoring alerts. I can see that there is a few that are done by default and the notification is sent to the product owner, but I want to create some custom ones using Terraform.

I want the notifications to be sent to a specific Slack channel, but due to company restrictions I cannot integrate the Slack application with the Mongodb Atlas console. My other option was to use a outgoing webhook. I can see there are options for webhook with Terraform:

```
resource "mongodbatlas_alert_configuration" "test" {
  project_id = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
  event_type = "OUTSIDE_METRIC_THRESHOLD"
  enabled    = true

  notification {
    type_name     = "WEBHOOK"
    webhook_url   = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXX/YYYYY/ZZZZZ"
    interval_min  = 5
    delay_min     = 0
  }

  matcher {
    field_name = "CLUSTER_NAME"
    operator   = "EQUALS"
    value      = "SECONDARY"
  }

  metric_threshold_config {
    metric_name = "SYSTEM_MEMORY_USED"
    operator    = "GREATER_THAN"
    threshold   = 80.0
    units       = "RAW"
    mode        = "AVERAGE"
  }`
```

But I am unsure how to point it at a specific Slack channel. Any help would be appreciated!

I tried using the above code block but the alert did not set up a Slack notification.

Comment: From what I have seen in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mongodb/mongodbatlas/latest/docs/resources/alert_configuration#api_token), there are `api_token` and `channel_name` arguments inside of the `notifications` block which should be used for Slack notifications.

Answer (score 0):

this is Zuhair from MongoDB. If you are still blocked feel free free to post a new issue on our GitHub repo and happy to have team take a deeper look: https://github.com/mongodb/terraform-provider-mongodbatlas/issues

Thank you and hope your database migration is going well!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).